# how to remove username and password from admin in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am beginner to `Mongodb`. I am using `mongodb 2.6`,I have created username and Password for admin database. I want to know how to give the access to other operation like create new database,insert,etc.. and also how to remove the username and password from admin..

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend removing the username/password from the admin role. You should ensure this password is strong as well.

It's probably a good idea to create a new user with a more limited set of privileges (ideally the minimum necessary) for the user, perhaps through one of `mongo's` predefined roles.

For example, you could have an administrator role that can create new databases and perform other admin tasks, but then a more restricted role for another admin-type user who can create new collections, indexes, etc. with say, the `readWrite` role.

See the `2.6` docs for details as some of this changed in this `2.6`:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#database-administration-roles

Note: most of this advice is pretty generic and would apply to most any database. You want to make access as restrictive as you can by default and then only relax it when absolutely necessary.